# How to increase margins using a .cls file

Tags: margins

Sorry if this an easy question (relatively new to Latex!), however I'm getting a bit confused by this pre-done .cls file which I am trying to understand.

I'm trying to decrease the margins in the A4 document, as currently the gaps are quite large and was wondering if anyone could give any light to what I could/should change?

```
\newcommand{\bookclass}{book}

% Font size, this option is passed to book class. T.G. : use regular, 10- to 12-
% point size for text. Default is 12pt.
\newcommand{\@ftsize}{}
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\renewcommand{\@ftsize}{10pt}}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\renewcommand{\@ftsize}{11pt}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand{\@ftsize}{12pt}}

% Left side margin. 
% [1.5in], [1.7in]
% T.G. : the left margin must be at least 1.5 inches (recommend 1.7). default is
% 1.7, unless [1.5in] is specified.
\newcommand{\@lmarwidth}{}
\newcommand{\@smarwidth}{}
\newcommand{\@texwidth}{}

\DeclareOption{1.5in}{%
  \renewcommand{\@lmarwidth}{.5in}%
  \renewcommand{\@smarwidth}{.0in}%
  \renewcommand{\@texwidth}{6.0in}%
}
\DeclareOption{1.7in}{%
  \renewcommand{\@lmarwidth}{.7in}%
  \renewcommand{\@smarwidth}{.0in}%
  \renewcommand{\@texwidth}{5.8in}%
}

% One and half or double spacing?
% [onehalf], [double]
% T.G. : use either double or 1.5 line spacing for the body of text. default is
% double, unless [onehalf] is specified.
\newcommand{\@spacing}{}
\DeclareOption{onehalf}{\renewcommand{\@spacing}{\onehalfspacing}}
\DeclareOption{double}{\renewcommand{\@spacing}{\doublespacing}}
\AtEndOfClass{\@spacing}

% Draft or final version?
% [preprint], [submission]
% Default is submission.
\newif\if@preprint

\DeclareOption{preprint}{\@preprinttrue}
\DeclareOption{submission}{\@preprintfalse}

% [seploa]
\newif\if@seploa
\@seploafalse
\DeclareOption{seploa}{\@seploatrue}

% Other options are passed to the book class.
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\bookclass}}

% These are the default options.
\ExecuteOptions{12pt,1.7in,double,submission}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\if@preprint
\PassOptionsToClass{twoside,openright}{\bookclass}
\else
\PassOptionsToClass{oneside,openany}{\bookclass}
\fi

\PassOptionsToClass{\@ftsize}{\bookclass}

\LoadClass[letterpaper,onecolumn]{\bookclass}

% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Set up page layout.

% \evensidemargin is used when [twoside] is set (by [preprint]).
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{25pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{25pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{\@texwidth}
% Other margins. T.G.: all other margins must be at least 1 inch.
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{.5in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.3in}
\setlength{\footskip}{.5in}
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: If this is for submission to a journal or publisher and this is a format provided by them, you ought not change the page layout at all.

Comment: @cfr This was a template from WriteLaTeX which I found and am just using to try out new ideas to understand LaTeX better

Comment: If you are just starting with LaTeX, it would be better not to tangle with class files at this point but to experiment with different ways to format a document using a standard class. For example, use the `book` class and then load `geometry` and use it to configure your overall page layout (margins, skips etc.). It is not recommended to specify this stuff using the low level commands unless you need to. Basically, something like `geometry` is less error prone and provides a much more robust solution.

Comment: Have you tried `\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}`?

Comment: Don't forget to use the `showframe` option for `geometry`. It is very useful.

Comment: @cfr Thank you for the tips, I've just been messing around with LaTeX, so just wanted to try something new.

Comment: @nicolai.rostov That does work if I add it to the main .tex file, however was wondering what I should be changing to the .cls file instead?

Comment: `\RequirePackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}` in that case.

Comment: @Lawrence: Apart from changing margins etc., it is a tedious task to write a class. I believe, there are at least three (good) class schemes (LaTeX standard, memoir, KOMA) which can be used out of the box, fine tuning can be done with the already mentioned  `\geometry` package in conjunction with other packages. Please do also consider readability of your document as well as binding correction etc.